# Лучше скачать сайт или переверстать?

Tags: html, css, конструктор, копирование

Есть одностраничный сайт на конструкторе. Мне нужно его скачать и добавить еще три страницы. Как будет быстрее. Переверстать или скачать и переделать в нужных местах, что бы гугл не ругался. Если качать, то есть ли способ скачать сразу с папкой картинок и скриптов

Answer (score 0):

Есть программа для скачивания сайтов HTTrack, но, боюсь, большинство современных сайтов она скачает с половиной действующего функционала.

Если у сайта есть функционирующий бэкэнд, то скачать такое невозможно.

Comment: на сайте есть js файлы, как модальное окно или анимации.

Comment: но лучше же скачать и доработать? Чем заново верстать. Гугл ругаться не будет?

Comment: @Triceps Senju всё равно придётся править <header>